# VB.net For Each Loop with If Statement Error

Tags: vb.net

When this code is ran, Visual Studio gives the error:

InvalidOperationException was unhandled
List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.

```
    Dim counter As Integer
    For Each x In lstWinners.Items
        If x = lstWinners.SelectedItem Then
            counter += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]
http://i.cubeupload.com/lIoWDg.png

EDIT:

This can be fixed by adding this line at the beginning:
Dim anything as string = lstWinners.Text

But why does this error happen, and why does this fix it?

Comment: Are you just trying to count the number of selected items? If so, would using lstWinners.SelectedItems.Count not be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm actually trying to count the items in the list that have the same value as the selected item. This is assuming there is only one item selected.

Comment: Where are you placing 'Dim anything as string = lstWinners.Text' ?   Try to replace your *For Each - Loop* with a *For -Loop*.

Comment: It goes right at the beginning. It works, so I'm just looking for some explanation as to why.

Comment: Ok. This makes no scence to me. Have you tried to replace your *foreach-loop* with a *for-loop*  without adding your line *Dim anything as string = lstWinners.Text*?

Answer (score 0):

When you are going over the list with for each it kind of "locks" the array. A good way around this is to just copy the array for the iteration.

Just use Array.Copy(source, target, target.Length) where your source would be lstWinners.Items and target is an array you declare. Then do your for each loop on the array. Something like:

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim tempcopy(lstWinners.Items.Count) As String
Array.Copy(lstWinners.Items, tempcopy, tempcopy.Length)
    For Each x In tempcopy
        If x = lstWinners.SelectedItem Then
            counter += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why it would be fixed by adding this line of code at the beginning of my original code? Dim anything as string = lstWinners.Text

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be creating a copy in the background of lstWinners which side steps the lock that you were running into later.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is seeing the = operator as the assignment operator instead.
Try this code instead:

```
Dim counter As Integer
For Each x In lstWinners.Items
    If x Is lstWinners.SelectedItem Then
        counter += 1
    End If
Next
```

Is explicitly compares equality on objects, so it removes any potential ambiguity.

Comment: It's definitely the comparison operator there. (biggest gripe with VB .. = means what exactly? depends!)

Comment: Actually, I am going to say no. They come out of the items as an Object, not a string, so Is has to be used, because = is the assignment operator on Objects. When he dim's it as a string, it all of a sudden works, because now it's using the string's = operator (comparison).

Comment: Just tested, this does not solve the problem. It gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your items are strings and you want to count the items with the same text then you could use

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim x = lstWinners.SelectedItem.ToString()
counter = lstWinners.Items.Cast(Of String).Count(Function(z) z = x)
```

However, your code should not give that error unless there is something else that is running and modify your list (a separate thread?)

Comment: Yeah, thats wired, because  the error only occurs if the enumerated is getting modified while its enumerating.

Comment: There shouldn't be something else modifying the list as this is the only thing this program is supposed to do.